# How to do Kendo UI MVVM UI automation test?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, kendo-mvvm

My application is built using Kendo UI MVVM

When I try to validate the value on a textfield, it always returns empty string. It is because the application is using Kendo UI MVVM. All values are data bind.

When I look at the DOM tree, it will be

```
<input id="txtWorkPhone" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: selectedParentContact.WorkPhone">
```

Currently, I am using Selenium Java to do automation testing by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can be done using `JavascriptExecutor`

Use this code -

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtWorkPhone"));

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    String value = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].value", element) ;

    System.out.println("WorkPhone = "+value);
```

As It will return the bind value of input textbox

Comment: Hi Narendra Do you have any idea why the above solution does not work in some forms. It returns an empty string. Thanks

Comment: Sometime `javascript` not get loaded in your browser so you need to  inject `javascript` in your browser and then do your required functionality but it not necessary, everywhere it will be same. What you are looking for thing can be different

Comment: When I look at the HTML code they are the same <input id="txtCatalogueNo" class="k-textbox" maxlength="25" data-bind="value: selectedCatalogue.CatalogueNumber">. The only different is this field is on the ContentHeaderSection. Other one, which is working, is in tab content

Comment: What do you mean?